# Added protocol to AppDelegate not registering

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, protocols, delegation, appdelegate

As soon as my first view loads my location controller calls `-(void)locationFound` to its delegate, which is `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` (my AppDelegate)
I have a corresponding protocol that just asks for that one required method locationFound.

I have a protocol adherence declared like so in my AppDelegate header:

```
@interface ProgramAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, LocationFoundProtocol>
```

Everything works fine - - except I get a warning when I assign the delegate in my location controller - like so:

```
self.positioningBrain.positioningNetworkingDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

It tells me:

```
Assigning to 'id<LocationFoundProtocol>' from incompatible type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'
```

It seems like it simply doesn't see that my AppDelegate does in fact conform to my specified protocol - even though it is declared in the header.

Is there some reason why XCode registers this mismatch?  I'm not too surprised my code works, as protocols should all be semantics anyhow, but if there's a better way to do it I'd like to know.

Comment: just making certain -- did you "`#import "ProgramAppDelegate.h"`" at the top of wherever you're trying to do that assignment?

Comment: You have to cast `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW24

Answer (score 3):

the delegate property of UIapplication returns the following type

```
id<UIApplicationDelegate>
```

You must cast the returned type to your AppDelegates type

```
... = (MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
```

Comment: self.positioningBrain.positioningNetworkingDelegate = (ProgramAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; doesn't work - for some reason, it tells me it can't find ProgramAppDelegate* - even though that's the class I'm working in.           Use of undeclared identifier 'LocalChatAppDelegate'
Expected expression
Missing '[' at start of message send expression
Expected ']'

Comment: You have to add #import "LocalChatAppDelegate.h" to the top of the file your using the cast in.

Comment: Remember all types you use have to be imported with #import "whatever.h" for the compiler to see them in the implementation

Comment: Oops, wasn't even in AppDelegate.  Just hardcore derping.  
Shift enter thanks too.  Thanks.

Comment: The cast itself doesn't need to import a header (a forward declaration would do). Importing the header is necessary for it to know that the class implements that protocol, so it doesn't generate a warning.

Comment: You cant access methods or members of a class imported with a forward declaration only a type name, hes about to call a method on it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` is of type `ProgramAppDelegate`; all it knows is that the delegate method of UIApplication returns `id<UIApplicationDelegate>`. If you want to suppress the warning, you'll need to assign `positioningNetworkingDelegate` from some place where you know the full type of the application delegate. (For example, if you were in the delegate's own code, you could just say `positioningBrain.positioningNetworkingDelegate = self` and that would work).

You could also cast it to convince the compiler this is valid:

```
self.positioningBrain.positioningNetworkingDelegate = (ProgramAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Many people make a shortcut function or macro for this purpose. Something like:

```
#define APPDEL ((ProgramAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```